# GWT - constructing a new ImageData / Bitmap

Tags: gwt, bitmap, html5-canvas

I wish to create a new, empty bitmap, manually draw on it, and only then draw it onto a canvas.

This bitmap should not based on any existing image or existing canvas.

Is there a way to create such a bitmap in GWT? The best solution I can find is creating a dummy canvas, then getting its ImageData through context2d. I can hardly believe that this is the right way to do this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Take care, due to limitations, your app will not run on google app engine.

[JRE GAE white list](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist)

Comment: Is there a particular class in the whitelist that can help me overcome this issue?

Comment: in the past, I searched how to generate qr codes, I can't remember which library but I get troubles with class such as image writer on something like this.
May be you could have a look in "zxing" code.
Another way could be using fileservices ( https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/files/FileService )